# Customized view by Category but only show the last copies

Tags: list-view

Say, I have a document library with Group by Category. Now say Sales category has 6 items which can by further group by Quarter. So 1st quarter has 2 items, 2nd quarter has 2 items and 3rd quarter has 2 items.

Is there a way to display just the 3rd quarter items? Now, for the Training category only 4 items are added (so far) meaning 3rd quarter items are still missing. So the view should show items from the 2nd quarter as those the latest copy.

{I know a work around to add a ShowItem Y/N type column and maintain it that way but end user don't want to maintain the view this way}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work around kind of works for me.

Sort > Sort by Modified (Descending)
Group By > Category (Ascending)
Item Limit > 2 "Limit the total number of items returned to be specified amount." selected

Then I open the view in SP Designer (Advanced View) so I could see XSLTListViewAll

Found are SPAN area for Group Total and set Display:None to hide the total number in the group by counter.